# How to use laravel Eloquent to take just one field?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am new in Laravel and I am watching a video tutorial that is teaching Laravel 3, unfortunately Laravel 4 is very different with laravel 3 and I don't know why? and I am afraid that maybe laravel 5 will be so different with laravel 4.

I am going to select all data about one field from my users table:

```
    $user=new user;
    $username=$user::find(1)->username;
    return $username;
```

The top code is working true but just return the username of a user that it's id is equal to 1, But I want to do something like below:

```
$user=new user;
$username=$user::all()->username;
return $username;
```

This code has error **$user::all()->username;** and the **error** is :

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$username

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `lists()` function, described [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#selects)
It will return an array with all the values of one property.

(Also you don't need to create an instance to retrieve all users)

```
$usernames = User::lists('username');
```

If you'd like to have another column as key of your array (e.g. the id) do this:

```
$usernames = User::lists('username', 'id');
```

---

Don't be worried about Laravel 5. Some things will change but many things will stay the same. Including everything about Eloquent and the DB querying in general (at least as far as I know)

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the diffrent bettween **all()** and **get()**

Comment: @Kermani `all()` can only be used staticly. `get()` doesn't have such restriction.

Comment: @Kermani This is a bit an off-topic question for this post. Could you post a new question asking about the difference? Also, other users would find it more quickly this way.

Comment: All this method does is being static proxy for `get`, however it deosn't need to be called, since `get` can also be called 'statically', ie. being forwarded to underlying `Eloquent\Builder` thanks to the magic methods.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk while this is totally correct, I have my doubts the OP  understands it... (no offence Kermani)

Comment: @lukasgeiter you can't save them all ;)

Comment: Hahaha true @JarekTkaczyk. Well I might even post a question (and answer) myself since I couldn't find any question on that topic already...